# Trying to compare the value of two cells in react, then change style based on value

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-table, react-table-v7

I am new to react.

I made a table using react-table module I'm trying to highlight all the cells where the cell in the first column doesn't equal the cell next to it in column 2.

here is my table component:

```
const Table = () => {

    const columns = useMemo(() => Columns, [])
    const data = useMemo(() => mock, [])
    
    

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
        state,
        setGlobalFilter,
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    }, useGlobalFilter)

    const { globalFilter } = state

    return (
        < >
         
            <SearchBar searchValue={globalFilter} setSearchValue={setGlobalFilter}/>
            
           
        <div>
            
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>

                    
                    {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) =>(
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                        
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {
                        rows.map((row) =>{
                            prepareRow(row)
                            return (
                                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                    {row.cells.map((cell, index)=> {
                                        return <td {...cell.getCellProps()} style = {{
                                            backgroundColor:{rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value ? 'red': null}
                                        }}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                    })} 
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </>
    )


        

    
}


export default Table
```

when I run this I get two errors

> expected ',' at
>
> backgroundColor:{rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value
> ? 'red': null}
>
> expected ':' at
>
> backgroundColor:{rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value
> ? 'red': null}

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Object is `key`:`value` based and your `{rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value ? 'red': null}` is object without key. I guess you wanted: `backgroundColor: rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value ? 'red': null` without `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
{backgroundColor:(rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value ? 'red': null)}
```

use parentheses not braces.